# how to fix the error Wait-Job cmdlet cannot finish working, because one or more jobs are blocked waiting for user interaction

Tags: powershell, scripting, terraform

I have a function which requires the user to enter Y or N to delete a file and I'm trying to run this whole function as a start-job function. My code is:

```
$JobFunction2 = {
    function init {
      
        try {
            $output = terraform init
            $path = Get-Item -Path ".\"
            $in = $output | Select-String "Terraform has been successfully initialized!"
            if ($in) {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor GREEN 'Initialization successfull'
            }
            else { 
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor YELLOW 'Intiialization failed Please enter Y to delete the .terraform folder'
                $fail = del $path/.terraform -Force
                $output = terraform init 
                return $fail, $output
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Error Occurred while Initializing the folder and the path is: $path"
        }
    }
}
Start-Job -InitializationScript $JobFunction2 -ScriptBlock { init } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

When I'm running the start-job it shows "Wait-Job cmdlet cannot finish working, because one or more jobs are blocked waiting for user interaction". But if I'm calling  only the function name 'init' without starting a job it works perfectly. Is there any way I could prompt the user to input Y or No so that the function could work in start-job?

Comment: Without some research around how the job execution context works this is a pure guess..., is it possible that one is executed as admin or privileges to the folder structure you want to work with, hence `.init()` does work. Whilst inside a job the users pace context has changed and therefore user input is required...

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for... do you want to know if `Read-Host` is possible within a Job?

Comment: Thank you guys for your response.. I have found a solution for this issue...I changed the $fail to $fail = Remove-Item $path/.terraform -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false
and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fail = Remove-Item $path/.terraform -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false
```

this helped me to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is setting your job's `State` to `Blocked`, but if the question is:
 *Is there any way I could prompt the user to input `Y` or `N` so that the function could work in `Start-Job`?*
The answer is yes, below you can see an example of how it can be implemented, note that I'm using a `while` loop instead of [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-7.2).

According to the documentation, the cmdlet has a `-Sate` parameter that takes a `<JobState>` argument but I couldn't get it to work. Even tried:

```
Wait-Job -Any -Force -State Blocked
```

And got the same error as you, so here is the brute force solution you can use:

```
function init {
    
    'Initializing Function {0}' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
    
    do
    {
        $choice = Read-Host 'Waiting for user input. Continue? [Y/N]'
        if($choice -notmatch '^y|n$')
        {
            'Invalid input.'
        }
    }
    until ($choice -match '^y|n$')

    if($choice -eq 'y')
    {
        'Continue script...'
    }
    else
    {
        'Abort script...'    
    }
}

$funcDef = [scriptblock]::Create("function init { $function:init }")

$job = Start-Job -InitializationScript $funcDef -ScriptBlock { init }
$desiredState = 'Stopped', 'Completed', 'Failed'

while($job.State -notin $desiredState)
{
    if($job.State -eq 'Blocked')
    {
        Receive-Job $job
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

$job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```